# Почему в nodejs не задаются свойства класса?

Tags: node.js

Почему у меня не получается положить в свойство класса обект? 
я делаю this.profile = result[0]; что бы положить в свойство класса результат выборки sql запроса но в следующей конструкции после then когда пытаюсь его получить console.log(this.profile); он undefined, кто знает в чем магия?

```
function user() {
    database.call(this);
    this.profile = new Object();
    this.UP();
};
user.prototype = Object.create(database.prototype);
user.prototype.constructor = user;

user.prototype.Profile = function(){
    var getUserAgent =  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.dbCon.query("SELECT ...;",
        function (err, result, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('-> getUserAgent');
            this.profile = result[0]; // result[0] содержит нужные мне данные
            resolve(result[0]);
        }
        );
    }).then((result) => {
        console.log(this.profile);
        console.log('<- UserAgent');
        return true;
    }).catch((e) => {
        console.log('error: ', e)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function (err, result, fields) {    
  ...
  // это не стрелочная функция, здесь "this" другой
  this.profile = result[0];
```

Это стрелочная функция:

```
(err, result, fields) => {    
  ...
  this.profile = result[0];
```

где `this` будет такой же как в той функции, где эта стрелочная функция определена, а та функция - тоже стрелочная, значит в ней `this` такой же как ... и в конце концов зависит от того, как вызывается метод `Profile`.

Comment: не понял, а как мне писать что бы это нормально работало?